# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when I am trying to upload a file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3, uploadify

When I am trying to upload file the error is coming like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

### assignmnet.php

```
<form id="assignmentsubmit">
    <div class="submityourwork">
        <h4 class="sm bold">Submit your work</h4>
                                                    
        <div class="text-form-editor">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/public/images/editor-demo-1.jpg" alt="">
            <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $courseId?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tid" value="<?php echo $topicId?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $user?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="content" value=""/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title of text" name="title">
            <textarea placeholder="Your content start here" name="description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
                                                
    <div id="disc"></div>
    <div class="form-action">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon md-upload"></i></a>
        <div class="tr-file reffile" style="display:none">
        <ul>       
            <li class="form-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="trigger-file">
                    <span class="name-file refname"></span>
                    <span class="size-file refsize"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-file">
                   <i class="icon md-close-2 referenceclose"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>                                   
    </div>
    <div id="contentupload" ></div>
</div> 
<input type="submit" id ="switch" value="Submit"  class="abc submit mc-btn-3 btn-style-1">
</form>
```

The above code is my html code to select a file from here.

The js is in the same file like below

```
<script>
        var urljs = "<?php echo base_url()?>";
    </script>
    <script>
        
        $("#contentupload").uploadify({
            height        : 30,
            swf           : urljs+'/public/js/uploadify.swf',
            uploader      : urljs+'/user/UploadifyController/uplaodfiles',
            folder        : "../../../uploads",
            width         : 120,
            fileSizeLimit : '150MB',
            fileTypeDesc  : 'Video Files',
            fileTypeExts  : '*.mp4; *.flv',
            debug           : false,
            removeCompleted : false,
            formData      : {
                folder : '../../private/<?php echo $userId;?>/beforeconvert',
                folder1 : '../../private/<?php echo $userId;?>'
            },
            onSelect: function(file) {
                alert('fdsdsfdsfdsfdsf');
                $("#contentupload-queue").find(".uploadify-queue-item:not(':last')").each(function(){
                    var contentUploadQueueID = $(this).attr('id');
                    var files = $('#contentupload').data('uploadify').queueData.files;
                    delete files[contentUploadQueueID];
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                
            },
            onUploadStart : function(file) {
                appendContentInputElement();
                disableSwitchBtn();
            },
            
            onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {
                $("[name=content]").val(file.name);
                $(".reffile").show();
                $(".refname").text(file.name);
                $(".refsize").text(file.size);
                $("#contentupload-queue").empty();
                removeContentInputElement();
                enableSwitchBtn();          
            },
            onUploadError : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                removeBannerInputElement();
                enableSwitchBtn();
            },
            onCancel : function(file) {
                removeBannerInputElement();
                enableSwitchBtn();
            }   
            
        });
        
        function appendContentInputElement(){
            $("#assignmentsubmit").prepend("<input type='hidden' class='basic_information_element' name='basic_element_content' value='uploading.....'>");
        }
        
        function disableSwitchBtn(){
            $("#switch").attr("disabled", true).addClass("stbtn-yle-6").removeClass("btn-style-1").val("Uploading ...");
        }
        
        function removeContentInputElement(){
            $("#assignmentsubmit").find('input[name=basic_element_content]').remove();
        }
        
        function enableSwitchBtn(){
            if($("input.basic_information_element").length <= 0){
                $("#switch").attr("disabled", false).addClass("btn-style-1").removeClass("btn-style-6").val("Submit");
            }
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            cancelreference();
            function cancelreference(){
                $('.referenceclose').unbind("click");
                $('.referenceclose').on("click",function(e){
                    $(".reffile").hide();
                    $("[name=content]").val("");
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
```

When I clicked to select a file window is opened to select a video but it not selected and nothing shows in chrome network tool.

Comment: is it a full code? .. idont find apply anywhere

Comment: it shows in this file `(vaidation.jquery.js:1299)`